# How do you set up Android Studio to use project view for new project?

Tags: android, android-studio

Right now, when you create a new project in Android Studio, the project tools window opens with Android view by default. Is there a way to make it open in Project view instead?

Answer (score 10):

I found it:

Go to Android Studio → Help → Edit Custom Properties

Click “yes” if prompted to create a new properties file

In the idea.properties file, enter studio.projectview=true

Save and restart Android Studio, and all your projects will now be opened in Project View by default!

From this link: https://medium.com/@margaretmz/android-studio-a-few-tips-and-tricks-5de4486799c9#.gt8w0nfbw